# Firebase / Angularfire 0.9 - Create new user and profile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

To create a new user in Angularfire 0.9 I can use the $firebaseAuth service and the $createUser method.

However from what I can tell this method does not return any of the new users credentials. So if I want to add profile to that user what is the best way to retrieve that users Auth Data, specifically the "uid", so I can save the profile data for my new user. Below is an example of what I am trying to do

```
var FIREBASEURL = "https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com"

var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASEURL);
$rootScope.authObj = $firebaseAuth(ref);

var newUser = {
  email: "email@email.com",
  password: "password",
  displayName: "Display Name",
  favFood: "Food"
};

$rootScope.authObj.$createUser(newUser.email, newUser.password).then(function() {

  console.log("User created successfully!");

  // Retrieve new Auth Data specifically uid    

  var newAuthData = ??????????

  // Remove password from object and create user profile

  delete newUser.password;
  newUser.timestamp = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

  var userRef = new Firebase(FIREBASEURL + '/users/');
  userRef.child( newAuthData.uid ).set(newUser);

}).catch(function(error) {

  console.error("Error: ", error);

});
```

Comment: To partially answer my own question, as per the Firebase Javascript API 2.0.5 changelog "Expose created user via second argument in callback to createUser().". This gives you the new Auth's "uid" which I needed. I assume the Angularfire library will be updated accordingly and I will update this question when it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 0.9.1, the uid will be returned with the promise. For example:

```
var FIREBASEURL = "https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com"

var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASEURL);
$rootScope.authObj = $firebaseAuth(ref);

var newUser = {
  email: "email@email.com",
  password: "password",
  displayName: "Display Name",
  favFood: "Food"
};

$rootScope.authObj.$createUser(newUser.email, newUser.password).then(function(authData) {
  console.log(authData.uid); //should log new uid.
  return createProfile(newUser, authData);
});


function createProfile(authData, user){         
  var profileRef = $firebase(ref.child('profile'));
  return profileRef.$set(authData.uid, user);
};
```

That should get you going. The key is to pass the returned promise (**authData** in my example) to the follow-on function.

In 0.9.0, it is necessary to call an authentication method in order to obtain the user's uid.

Comment: While this does answer the question, it's generally going to be a good idea to authenticate the user before allowing them to write to their profile, as this simplifies security rules considerably and removes the complexities of anonymous writes to profiles (which are many).

Comment: Is there a "pretty" solution on how to create, login and add a profile for a user? Also the opposite way, remove user and profile. Or will there always be promises and nested function calls to do this? Thinking of the possibility where the user gets successfully removed but not the profile in still there. I guess a batch job that runs every now and then could clean up stuff that fails...

Comment: @Kato What I do is simply ask for email and password. After sign up, redirect to login. Then user signs in to meet the other extra stuff on profile page. At that point, I know the user is logged in, so saving away is pretty straightforward.